# Qt: Using signals and slots between two child threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm new to Qt, and C++ in general, and I'm trying to make a program that runs two child threads, threadA and threadB. Both threads are created in main.cpp like so:

```
ThreadA threadA;
threadA.start();
ThreadB threadB;
threadB.start();
```

The two threads then run independently.
I need to make threadA able to call a method in threadB, passing data as an argument in the process. I have tried using signals and slots, by adding this to my main.cpp:

```
QThread::connect(&threadA, SIGNAL(mySignal(uint)),
    &threadB, SLOT(mySlot(uint)));
```

Where threadA::mySignal(uint) is used in a:

```
//a.h
signals:
  void mySignal(unsigned int blah);
//a.cpp
  emit mySignal(42);
```

And threadB::mySlot(uint) is in b:

```
//b.h
public slots:
    void mySlot(unsigned int fluff);
//b.cpp
void threadB::mySlot(unsigned int fluff)
{ doStuff(fluff); ... }
```

The program compiles and runs sucessfully, but I get a message from QObject in my debug log:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QThread::mySlot(uint) in ../Project/main.cpp:42
```

Meaning that the compiler is looking in QThread instead of threadB for mySlot.
Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here? Any help would be gratly appreciated, and I can provide more details if nessesary.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but `QThread` doesn't have `mySlot`, for some reason the connect statement refers to `QThread` instead of your own derived class.

Comment: Yes; this is the problem, it's looking in QThread instead of threadB for the slot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your `threadb.h` (and possibly `threada.h`).

```
class ThreadB : public QObject 
{
   Q_OBJECT 
...
```

From the docs:
`All classes that contain signals or slots must mention Q_OBJECT at the top of their declaration. They must also derive (directly or indirectly) from QObject.`

I'm also assuming that you have subclassed `QThread`. You should know that `QThread` is used for managing threads, not processing data. You should subclass `QObject` instead. [Read this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/20691) for more info about that.

Comment: You're right, I had subclassed QThread. I have changed it to QObject, and added Q_OBJECT in threadb.h, but now I get two build errors: `/home/x/Test/threadb.h:9: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for threadb'`, in functions `~threadb` and `threadb`.

Comment: @user2652805 Did you try running qmake and rebuilding the project?

Answer (score 1):

First of all for the error you mentioned

> The program compiles and runs sucessfully, but I get a message from
>   QObject in my debug log:
>
> QObject::connect: No such slot QThread::mySlot(uint) in
>   ../Project/main.cpp:42

You are using `mySlot` and have defined `MySlot` please refer back your code

You have written

> QThread::connect(&threadA, SIGNAL(mySignal(uint)),
>       &threadB, SLOT(**mySlot**(uint)));

and defined

//b.h

```
public slots:
    void MySlot(unsigned int fluff);
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in writing the code up on SA, and is not in my actual code. Editing it now.

Comment: @user2652805  please post the working example so it will be very easy to solve your problem. Because when we post half of the codes that does not make sense. Please read http://sscce.org/